# PostgreSQL window function: row_number() over (partition col order by col2)

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, row-number

Following result set is derived from a sql query with a few joins and a union. The sql query already groups rows on Date and game. I need a column to describe the number of attempts at a game partitioned by date column.

```
Username   Game     ID   Date

johndoe1   Game_1   100  7/22/14 1:52 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   100  7/22/14 1:52 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   100  7/22/14 1:52 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   100  7/22/14 1:52 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   121  7/22/14 1:56 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   121  7/22/14 1:56 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   121  7/22/14 1:56 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   121  7/22/14 1:56 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   121  7/22/14 1:56 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   130  7/22/14 1:59 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   130  7/22/14 1:59 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   130  7/22/14 1:59 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   130  7/22/14 1:59 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   130  7/22/14 1:59 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   200  7/22/14 2:54 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   200  7/22/14 2:54 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   200  7/22/14 2:54 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   200  7/22/14 2:54 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   210  7/22/14 3:54 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   210  7/22/14 3:54 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   210  7/22/14 3:54 AM
johndoe1   Game_1   210  7/22/14 3:54 AM
```

I've the following sql query that enumerates the rows within the partition but not entirely correct since I want the count of the instances of that game based on the date and game. In this case johndoe1 has attempted at Game_1 five times partitioned by the time stamps.

This query returns result set below

```
select *
, row_number() over (partition by ct."date" order by ct."date") as "Attempts"
from csv_temp as ct

Username   Game     ID   Date             Attempts  (Desired Attempts col.)

johndoe1   Game_1   100  7/22/14 1:52 AM  1          1
johndoe1   Game_1   100  7/22/14 1:52 AM  2          1
johndoe1   Game_1   100  7/22/14 1:52 AM  3          1
johndoe1   Game_1   100  7/22/14 1:52 AM  4          1
johndoe1   Game_1   121  7/22/14 1:56 AM  1          2
johndoe1   Game_1   121  7/22/14 1:56 AM  2          2
johndoe1   Game_1   121  7/22/14 1:56 AM  3          2
johndoe1   Game_1   121  7/22/14 1:56 AM  4          2
johndoe1   Game_1   121  7/22/14 1:56 AM  5          2
johndoe1   Game_1   130  7/22/14 1:59 AM  1          3   
johndoe1   Game_1   130  7/22/14 1:59 AM  2          3
johndoe1   Game_1   130  7/22/14 1:59 AM  3          3
johndoe1   Game_1   130  7/22/14 1:59 AM  4          3
johndoe1   Game_1   130  7/22/14 1:59 AM  5          3
johndoe1   Game_1   200  7/22/14 2:54 AM  1          4
johndoe1   Game_1   200  7/22/14 2:54 AM  2          4
johndoe1   Game_1   200  7/22/14 2:54 AM  3          4
johndoe1   Game_1   200  7/22/14 2:54 AM  4          4
johndoe1   Game_1   210  7/22/14 3:54 AM  1          5
johndoe1   Game_1   210  7/22/14 3:54 AM  2          5
johndoe1   Game_1   210  7/22/14 3:54 AM  3          5
johndoe1   Game_1   210  7/22/14 3:54 AM  4          5
```

Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://java.dzone.com/articles/difference-between-rownumber

Comment: Looking at the desired results, the only difference between the rows in a `(Desired Attempts col.)` group is the `Attempts` column. Perhaps you could just group by `Username, Game, ID`, add `count(1)` to get the number of attempts and add `row_number()` to get the `(Desired Attempts col.)` ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Consider `partition by` to be similar to the fields that you would `group by`, then, when the partition values change, the windowing function restarts at 1

EDIT
as indicated by a_horse_with_no_name, for this need we need `dense_rank()`
unlike `row_number()` `rank()` or `dense_rank()` repeat the numbers it assigns. `row_number()` must be a different value for each row in a partition. The difference between `rank()` and `dense_rank()` is the latter does not "skip" numbers.

For your query try:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by Username, Game order by ct."date") as "Attempts"
```

You don't partition by, and order by, the same field by the way; just order by would be sufficient if that was the need. It isn't here.

Comment: As in the example there is only one combination of username/game each row will get a different row_number with your statement (row_number() never generates duplicate numbers). It should be `dense_rank() over (partition by Username, Game order by ct."date")`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh dear quite correct - I was focused on the partitioning; thank you.

Comment: i was not creative enough to imagine that the "partition by" clause could accept more than one column and also i partitioned incorrectly. thanks to both of you!

Comment: When did this feature show up in postgres?  Is it relatively new?